# In vba how do I ReDim an array that is an element of another array

Tags: arrays, vba

I have 6 dynamic arrays. I want to include the names of these 6 arrays in another array. I then want to select, one at a time, each of the 6 dynamic arrays and ReDim the selected array to a size determined by the number of rows in an input file. The code I have used is giving me a compile error, see below:

```
    '================================================================
    ' DICTIONARIES
    '
    Dim FilePathNames               As Dictionary
    Dim WorkBookNames               As Dictionary
    Dim Sheet1Names                 As Dictionary
    Dim Sheet2Names                 As Dictionary
    '==============================================================
    ' GENERIC WORKBOOK OBJECT NAMES
    ' XXX(0) = FULL WORKBOOK PATH
    ' XXX(1) = WORKBOOK NAME
    ' XXX(2) = WORKSHEET1 NAME
    ' XXX(3) = WORKSHEET2 NAME (FieldXControl)
    ' XXX(4) = NUMBER OF ROWS IN WORKSHEET1
    ' XXX(5) = NUMBER OF ROWS IN WORKSHEET2
    Public XXX(6) As Variant
    Public CCC()  As Variant
    Public Keys() As String
    '================================================================
    Dim CMI()     As String
    Dim CML()     As String
    Dim CMN()     As String
    Dim CM1()     As String
    Dim CM2()     As String
    Dim CMS()     As String


    'Changed the code as suggested 
    CCC = Array(CMI, CML, CMN, CM1, CM2, CMS)


    'The following code is placed between a For loop 
    'Will loop through this 6 times conditioned on the For loop
    'Not a simple 0, 1, 2 etc.
    '
    Call DictionaryKeys(R)  'R is an integer conditioned by the For loop
    Call ObjectNames(Keys)
    Call ActivateFile       'A Sub that will activate XXX(1)
    XXX(4) = GetLastRowExt(XXX(1), XXX(2), "A") 'Function to get last row of XXX(2)
    XXX(5) = GetLastRowExt(XXX(1), XXX(3), "A") 'Function to get last row of XXX(3)

    ReDim CCC(N)(XXX(5) - 2)     '<===========Get a Sytax erro
                                 'Hope you can see what I'm trying to do
                                 'N is an integer between 0 and 5
                                 'How do I code for this?
    Go and do other stuff
    Next                         'End of For loop



    Public Sub ObjectNames(XXK As String)
    XXX(0) = FilePathNames.Item(XXK)
    XXX(1) = WorkBookNames.Item(XXK)
    XXX(2) = Sheet1Names.Item(XXK)
    XXX(3) = Sheet2Names.Item(XXK)
    End Sub
```

Comment: You filled `CCC` with strings, not arrays.  `CCC = Array(CMI, CML, CMN, CM1, CM2, CMS)`

Comment: OMW - That was a mistake, but after correcting still getting an error. I'm now getting a syntax error

Comment: on which line ?

Comment: On the CCC(N)(XXX(5) - 2) line. I think I've come to the conclusion that it's not possible to access an element of an array that's an element of another array. I wanted to do this so I didn't have chunks of repetitive code. And the number of elements within each of the inner arrays can vary.

Comment: In the above code, I've only shown 6 elements. In the live code, there are 15 elements, i.e. 15 arrays in groups of 3. I don't want to have 15 blocks of code. I want one block of code that can address 15 different arrays with a generic array name.

Answer (score 0):

You can't resize the inner array directly, but you can work around that quite easily:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim CMI()     As String
    Dim CML()     As String
    Dim CMN()     As String
    Dim CM1()     As String
    Dim CM2()     As String
    Dim CMS()     As String
    Dim CCC As Variant, arr, N As Long


    CCC = Array(CMI, CML, CMN, CM1, CM2, CMS)

    For N = LBound(CCC) To UBound(CCC)

       'ReDim CCC(N)(1 to N+5) 'no can do...

        arr = CCC(N)            'extract the inner array
        ReDim arr(1 To N + 5)   'resize it
        CCC(N) = arr            'put it back

    Next N

    For N = LBound(CCC) To UBound(CCC)
        Debug.Print LBound(CCC(N)), UBound(CCC(N))
    Next N
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know how it goes. I need to be able to work on all the arrays in one set of code. But you've given me a starting point and I'll see if I can develop it.